# Elastic Search error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Thanks for looking into this, I am trying to get basics of elastic search and while I was following [This medium tutorial](https://medium.com/naukri-engineering/elasticsearch-tutorial-for-beginners-using-python-b9cb48edcedc) so by executing a basic python script it gave me this following error

```
raise ConnectionError("N/A", str(e), e)       
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: 
ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object 
at 0x00000209314C2D88>: 
Failed to establish a new 
connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made 
because the target machine actively refused it) caused by: 
NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000209314C2D88>: 
Failed to establish a new connection:
[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

The python script

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost','port':9200}])

e1={
    "first_name":"nitin",
    "last_name":"panwar",
    "age": 27,
    "about": "Love to play cricket",
    "interests": ['sports','music'],
}

e2={
    "first_name" :  "Jane",
    "last_name" :   "Smith",
    "age" :         32,
    "about" :       "I like to collect rock albums",
    "interests":  [ "music" ]
}
e3={
    "first_name" :  "Douglas",
    "last_name" :   "Fir",
    "age" :         35,
    "about":        "I like to build cabinets",
    "interests":  [ "forestry" ]
}

res = es.index(index='megacorp',doc_type='employee',id=1,body=e1)
print(res['created'])
```

Could you please help me with this, Also I installed elasticsearch by **pip install**

Comment: can you show the output of curl localhost:9200 and I am hoping your ES and code both are running on same machine?

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja here ```curl : The URI prefix is not recognized.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl localhost:9200
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:  
   ) [Invoke-WebRequest], NotSupportedException   
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletIEDomNotS  
   upportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comma   
  nds.InvokeWebRequestCommand ```

Comment: What exactly you didn't understand in my first comment ??

Comment: what is curl and do I need it to run elastic search,

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja Yes I am

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227285/discussion-between-elasticsearch-ninja-and-pawan-nirpal).

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove 'port':9200 when you define the es.

Replace this:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost','port':9200}])
```

with this:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost'}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if process is running with below command

> `netstat -aon | findstr 9200`

This will show which port and which ip elasticsearch is listening to .
Then you can on browser do

> `localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true`

If this shows green you are good to go.

Comment: ```netstat -aon | findstr 9200``` did not do anything